# Could someone please explain a piece of Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a project in school, and as part of that I had to include radio buttons in my html form. Below is the Javascript code which some parts I don't quite understand. The code works fine. Could someone plz give me an explanation of how the code works.

```
var check = false; 
for (var i=0; i < document.ExamEntry.Level.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.ExamEntry.Level[i].checked)
      {
      var radiovalue = document.ExamEntry.Level[i].value;
      check =true; 
      var usermessage=confirm("You have chosen: ".concat(radiovalue));

          if(usermessage == false)
              {
                 var radiovalue = "";
                check = false;
              }
      }
   }
<!--I understand the code below, its just some parts of the above code.
if (check ==false)
       {
       msg+="ERROR:You must select an entry level \n";  
       document.getElementById ('Levelcell'). style.color = "red";
       result = false;
       }
```

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Can you please point out exactly what you don't understand?  Do you know what `for` and `if` do?  What `document` is in JavaScript?  What line exactly gives you trouble?

Comment: i++, Level[i].checked, Level[i].value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to help explain this:

```
var check = false; 

// set a variable 'i' from 0 up to the ExamEntry level length (so for each radio)
// if there are 10 items, this code will run 10 times, each time with 'i' a different value from 0 to 9
for (var i=0; i < document.ExamEntry.Level.length; i++)
   {

   // is the radio button checked? If so, do the stuff inside. If not, skip this part
   if (document.ExamEntry.Level[i].checked)
      {

      // set variable radiovalue to the value of the particular radio button
      var radiovalue = document.ExamEntry.Level[i].value;

      // set the check variable to true
      check =true; 

      // ask the user to confirm the value and set usermessage based on confirmation
      var usermessage=confirm("You have chosen: ".concat(radiovalue));

        // if the user hits no on confirm, it will reset the radiomessage to blank and check to false
        if(usermessage == false)
          {
             var radiovalue = "";
             check = false;
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur step by step code analysis. I'm confused what the i < document.ExamEntry.Level.length; i++ does...

Comment: That is the condition which keeps the loop going. i++ increments the value of i by 1, each time the for loop is run. ++ means add one to i. So the first time it runs, 'i' is 0. The second time it runs, 'i' is 1. And so on. It will stop when the condition in the middle is no longer met: i < document.ExamEntry.Level.length. So when i is greater than or equal to the number of Level items, it will stop.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All form elements are bound to the global HTML document variable. So somewhere on the page there must be a form with the name of `ExamEntry`:

```
<form name='ExamEntry' id='ExamEntry` ...
```

The next part refers to an element in the form. Since they are expecting a radio button, Level must be an input of type radio:

```
<label name="Level" id="1" type="radio" ....
<label name="Level" id="2" type="radio" ....
```

The loop iterates through all radio buttons. If the the button is checked, it grabs the checked value, and shows that message. If it does not find a checked button, then it displays an error message.

Comment: this is the main part I don't inderstand:for (var i=0; i < document.ExamEntry.Level.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.ExamEntry.Level[i].checked)
      {
      var radiovalue = document.ExamEntry.Level[i].value;

Comment: that's the part I just explained. `document` is a global html variable that refers to the DOM. So everything on the page is part of the document. There must be a form on the HTML page that has the name `ExamEntry` because all forms are bound to the document global variable. `Level` then must be an input button on that form.

Comment: for each input, it iterates through and looks for the selected radio button. If it finds one, it lets you know. Otherwise, it tells you that there is an error message.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in answering my question!!